# create simple python server to provide json for d3

Tags: python, webserver, d3.js

I use `d3.json()` to get json data for d3. And I tend to start a python server to provide that data. I find a snippet on the web:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = getJson() # json data is stored here
            self.request.sendall(json.dumps(data))
        except Exception, e:
            pass
```

When I request it via browser, I can see the result. However, d3 always returns null

```
d3.json('http://localhost', function(json) {
    alert(json)
});
```

What should I do to get the right result?

Comment: Have you tried printing the exception? I know its just a snippet/test, but that might get you on the right path. having a try catch and not printing the exception is not that helpful. Also have a look at the python debugger pdb (and its nicer cousin ipdb). that would enable you to workout whats going on potentially.

Comment: Actually no exception in the python side. And since the browser can get the right result, it further proves python does its job. I wonder if d3.json uses a different protocol than browser?

Comment: JSON is JSON. Although the content type could be different. Probably time to open of the dev tools and have a look at the differences in the request.